# Change height of columns in row when rows are stacked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can i change the height of the columns when columns are stacked in two rows using bootstrap?

https://jsfiddle.net/j6b49ngv/

if width ≥ 576px there should be two columns in one row with 100% height that works fine
and if width < 576px each column 100% width in two rows but the height should be 70% and 30% now the height is 50% each column. if i add height class for example h-75 and h-25 the size changes also when they aren't stacked.

```
<div class="container-fluid " id="wrapper">
        <div class="row equal h-100">
            <div class="col p-0 ">
                <div id="test">Canvas window</div>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 " id="sidebar">
              Sidebar für Konfigurator
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html,body {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
        }
          #test{
              height: 100%;
              background-color: blue;
          }
          #sidebar{
              background-color: aqua;
          }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using CSS `@media` queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width:576px) {
    #test {
        height: 70%;
    }
    #sidebar {
        height: 30%;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect  thank you! that was exactly what i was looking for